# UIAlertView invokes the telephone

Tags: ios

See this GIF

[image]

And this is the code

```
-(void)goGuestInfo
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[@"label.change" localize]
                                                        message:@"d"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:[@"label.cancel" localize]
                                              otherButtonTitles:[@"label.name" localize],
                                                                [@"label.email" localize],
                                                                [@"label.phone" localize], nil];
    [alertView show];
}

#pragma mark - Alertview delegate

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0: break;
        case 1: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:HotelBookingGuestEditNameSegue sender:nil]; break;
        case 2: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:HotelBookingGuestEditEmailSegue sender:nil]; break;
        case 3: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:HotelBookingGuestEditPhoneSegue sender:nil]; break;
        default: break;
    }
}
```

It only does it when I press "name" (i.e. case 1:).

I have never experienced this before and I've used alertviews many many times. Am i missing something obvious? After I go back to the app it will do the segues as it should.

Comment: Are you segue identifiers correct? Hard to debug, because the problem is likely not in the didDismissWithButtonIndex code.

Comment: @Jeff I've added an answer. It was just a category somewhere what was included (still haven't found it) in the codebase somewhere which had a method to call..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere deep down in the `#imports` there was/is a `didClickButtonAtIndex` that made a phone call.